# Capture iteration output into a data.frame in R

Tags: r, loops

I have a simple backtesting program written in R that calculates the testing period's return to date. Very simple. Not annualized, just overall buy-and-hold return. But not for just one set of parameters. It calculates these naive returns for a "set" of parameters. This requires looping and I've started by creating an explicit R loop to perform the operation. Here is the code and what it generates to console.

```
require(quantmod)

getSymbols("GLD")

for(i in seq(5, 15, 5))
  for(j in seq(50, 80, 15))

{
GLD$fast     <- SMA(Cl(GLD), n=i)     
GLD$slow     <- SMA(Cl(GLD), n=j)         

golden_cross <- Lag(ifelse(GLD$fast > GLD$slow, 1, -1))
golden_cross <- na.locf(golden_cross, na.rm=TRUE)

coin         <- ROC(Cl(GLD))*golden_cross

coin_box     <- cumprod(1+coin)
last_coin    <- coin_box[NROW(coin_box),]

coin_value   <- round((last_coin-1)*100, digits=2)

cat(i,j,coin_value,  "\n")
}
```

output:

```
5 50 9.96 
5 65 -26.37 
5 80 -21.92 
10 50 3.09 
10 65 -13.55 
10 80 -17.98 
15 50 -6.48 
15 65 -21.79 
15 80 -9.73
```

The output is taken out of the loop with the `cat()` function. This is useless to me. I'd like to have it return a `data.frame` object so I can perform analysis on it. Essentially, I'd like to remove the `cat()` call and use the looping process to create a `data.frame` object line by line. First column would be `i`, second column would be `j` and third column would be a value associated with the unique `i,j` iteration.

I'm already contemplating different approaches to vectorizing the script. I'm using the explicit R loop approach for now as a sort of place-holder.  I believe it's useful to solve this problem first before getting into re-factoring. If you disagree, I welcome your input.

EDIT :

The accepted answer below stands. But I was looking into the `cat()` function a little more closely and asked the question: Is there a way to change the default output of this function from the console to a file? As a matter of fact, there is. The following line redirects the output into a file. I'm saving the file to my home directory for illustration purposes, and calling it "test_result" (with no file extension because it looks cleaner that way). If you don't pass `append=TRUE` it will only return the last value derived from the loop.

```
    cat(i,j, coin_value,  "\n", file="~/test_result", append=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a combination of `apply` and `expand.grid` to get what you want :

```
fac1 <- seq(5, 15, 5)
fac2 <- seq(50, 80, 15)

Out <- apply(expand.grid(fac1,fac2),1,function(x){
  GLD$fast     <- SMA(Cl(GLD), n=x[1])
  GLD$slow     <- SMA(Cl(GLD), n=x[2])

  golden_cross <- Lag(ifelse(GLD$fast > GLD$slow, 1, -1))
  golden_cross <- na.locf(golden_cross, na.rm=TRUE)

  coin         <- ROC(Cl(GLD))*golden_cross

  coin_box     <- cumprod(1+coin)
  last_coin    <- coin_box[NROW(coin_box),]

  coin_value   <- round((last_coin-1)*100, digits=2)

return(c(x[1],x[2],Value=coin_value))
})
as.data.frame(t(Out))
```

Gives :

```
  Var1 Var2  Value
1    5   50   9.96
2   10   50   3.09
3   15   50  -6.48
4    5   65 -26.37
5   10   65 -13.55
6   15   65 -21.79
7    5   80 -21.92
8   10   80 -17.98
9   15   80  -9.73
```

Comment: Did not know about expand.grid. A perfectly suitable R built-in. Thanks.